# Animation: How to move the position of an equation in a continuous manner?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, positioning, animate

I want to make equations (or words) to continuously move in a page for a beamer talk. A simple example would be we have "A" on the left margin and "B" on the right margin and then "A" moves towards and below "B" to make the division B/A.

I thought about using the texpos package with the animate package so I did not have everything in a tikz picture. As I never used the animate package I'm looking for similar examples.

At TeXample, the examples I found of animation were about animating pictures and graphs. Here by "animation", all the questions I found mean changing an equation but not its position in a continuous manner.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below I present two options.

### Using the `animate` package

Here's a simple example, using the [`animate`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/animate) package. Initially you see "A" and "B" four centimeters apart and at the same height: when you play the animation (Acrobat Reader, please (restriction from `animate`)), "A" starts moving towards "B", and ends just below "B":

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}

\newcounter{tmp}
\stepcounter{tmp}
\def\Steps{20}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{}
\begin{center}
\begin{animateinline}[loop,poster=first,controls]{2}
\whiledo{\thetmp<\Steps}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
  decoration={
      markings,
      mark={
      at position \thetmp/(\Steps-1)
      with {\node {$A$};}}
      }]
    \coordinate (start) at (-2,0);
    \coordinate (end) at (2,0);
    \node at (end) {$B$};
    \path[postaction={decorate}]
      ([yshift=.35ex]start) to[out=-20,in=200] ([yshift=-3ex]end);
    \path[use as bounding box] (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \stepcounter{tmp}
  \ifthenelse{\thetmp<\Steps}
    {\newframe}
    {\end{animateinline}\relax}
}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

<sub>I don't know how to convert an animation of this kind to be uploaded.</sub>

The idea is to place "A" in a `\node` and to use a decoration (from the `decorations.markings` library) to make "A" move; the movement is given by changing the `at position` key for the decoration; the decoration is applied as a `postaction` to a curved path that ends just below "B".

Increasing the value for `\Steps` (set initially to 20) the movement will be more "continuous".

To have a visual guide of the path used, you can add `draw` to the path; i.e., replace

```
\path[postaction={decorate}]
      ([yshift=.35ex]start) to[out=-20,in=200] ([yshift=-3ex]end);
```

with

```
\path[draw,postaction={decorate}]
      ([yshift=.35ex]start) to[out=-20,in=200] ([yshift=-3ex]end);
```

### Using overlay specifications and a `\foreach` loop

Now the second option using overlay specifications and a loop to "fake" a real animation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\def\Steps{40}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (start) at (-3,0);
  \coordinate (end) at (3,0);
  \node at (end) {$B$};
  \foreach \Cont in {1,...,\Steps}
  \path<\Cont>[
  decoration={
    markings,
      mark=%
      at position \Cont/\Steps
      with {\node {A};}
  },
  postaction={decorate}]
    ([yshift=0.35ex]start) to[out=-30,in=210] ([yshift=-3ex]end);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]